# Authenticating to hosted TFS: TF30063: You are not authorized to access .visualstudio.com

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to connect to TFS on visualstudio.com through c# and am getting auth errors

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access [subdomain].visualstudio.com.

Here is how I'm trying to enter the username and the password, which are 100% for sure correct, I can login through the website by copying and pasting the u/n & pass, and the account is part of the collection and projects.

```
var tfsServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(new Uri(server));
tfsServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
tfsServer.Authenticate();
```

Comment: Have you tried including the domain in your NetworkCredential?

Comment: Exactly which line gets the exception? Please post the full exception.

Comment: You're connect to cloud tfs.  Have you enabled alternate credentials?  If so, are you supplying the alternate credentials?

Comment: @Nogusta I have tried it but it does not work.

Comment: @bryanmac I'm only supplying credentials how I have posted. what do you mean by enabling alternate credentials?

Comment: I answered with more details and a post.  I drove the creation of alternate creds so Xcode etc... could auth to git:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on visualstudio.com, it looks like you're connecting to hosted TFS.

You can enable alternate credentials and then use those credentials to auth via basic auth.

If you go to your profile in the web page for TFS (upper right hand corner in hosted), there's a credentials tab.  enter a username and password for alternate credentials and you can now send via basic auth header.

Programmatically in C# it's:

```
NetworkCredential netCred = new NetworkCredential(
            "altUserName",
            "altPassword");
BasicAuthCredential basicCred = new BasicAuthCredential(netCred);
```

Buck blogged about it here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2013/01/07/how-to-connect-to-tf-service-without-a-prompt-for-liveid-credentials.aspx

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I got it working with this information.
One thing to note for anyone else who has the problem, if you are conencting with TfsConfigurationServerFactory then you need to use .ClientCredenials instead of .Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows Service to connect TFS, then Log on it with administrator credential or a credential which have access to the TFS.

right click on Windows Service -> Properties -> Navigate Log on Tab -> Select This Account and give username and password..

It is worked for me hope it helps