# error TF30063: Force prompt for credentials when connecting programmatically to visualstudio.com

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I'm aware of alternate credentials ([Authenticating to hosted TFS: TF30063: You are not authorized to access .visualstudio.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17331955/4090370)) but I need users to be prompted for the credentials when connecting to visualstudio.com.

Similar in spirit to the code below, which does not work

```
var aTeamProjects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(m_oTfsCollectionUri);
aTeamProjects.ClientCredentials.PromptType = CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded;
aTeamProjects.Authenticate();
```

In the code above the `Authenticate`-request results in TF30063: You are not authorized to access .visualstudio.com.

Comment: It is a client app (e.g. windows form, console app) or a web app? Try it with var c = new VssClientCredentials();
 TfsTeamProjectCollection _tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(m_oTfsCollectionUri, c);_tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

Comment: @starain-MSFT I've added an update.

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue on another machine?

Comment: Could you share a simple project on the OneDrive?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153846/discussion-between-starain-msft-and-participant).

Comment: You may share a simple project on the OneDrive.

Comment: Does it prompt a window for authentication? You can clear credentials in Credential Manager, if doesn't work, clear C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\.IdentityService

Comment: It is a folder.

Comment: Do you mean clear credentials in Credential Manager works?

Comment: Sure, I added it to my answer.

Comment: Are there related credentials in Credential Manager? (You can open a new thread for new issue/question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is working on a new project with the code below. Then provide the credentials if it is asked when running an app.

```
var credentials = new VssClientCredentials();
credentials.PromptType = CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded;
var aTeamProjects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(m_oTfsCollectionUri, credentials);
aTeamProjects.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: Without ever being prompted for anything I kep getting: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access vs.com ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: @JohnGrabanski having the same problem with `VssClientCredentials` with 15.0 TFS client API. Have you found the reason ? [there is credentials prompt bug described](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/samples?view=azure-devops#visual-studio-sign-in-prompt-microsoft-account-or-azure-active-directory-backed-for-soap-services)