# TF30063: You are not authorized ... programmatic access not working

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

The code below provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230527/4090370) did work well for a while but now its throwing *Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: 'TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://{mysite}.visualstudio.com/.'* again.

```
var credentials = new VssClientCredentials();
credentials.PromptType = CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded;

var teamProjects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsCollectionUri, credentials);
teamProjects.EnsureAuthenticated();         // exception thrown
```

**Q** How can I fix this problem?

**Update** Strange enough,

1. before executing `teamProjects.EnsureAuthenticated();` the debugger reads `PromptIfNeeded` for `credentials.PromptType`.
2. after the exception has been thrown and the debugger has stopped the execution, it reads `DoNotPrompt` for `credentials.PromptType`.

**Observation**
The above code works perfectly well in a console application but fails to work in a windows forms application (i.e. it throws an exception).

**Q1** How can I make the above code work in a windows forms application?

Comment: answer link is dead. It's not pointing any sensible location

Comment: Checkout my blogpost. Maybe it can help?
http://damian.laczak.net.pl/blog/2017/09/14/tfs30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-possible-solution/

Comment: @Shoter I've fixed the link

Comment: Since it was working I expect some certificate to be obsolte ...

Comment: Is your issue fixed once you change DoNotPrompt to PromptIfNeeded? Could you please add an answer for this case?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT No, the exception is thrown and when the debugger stops and I inspect the credentials the PromptType has changed from PromptIfNeeded to DoNotPrompt - still no connection to VSTS.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, but the issue is similar: We use VSTS through Vistual Studio. If we do not use VSTS for an extended period of time (a few weeks), it will prompt that we are not authorized. A workaround we found, was to open the **Team Explorer** in Visual Studio, go to **Manage Connections**, right click any of the connections to VSTS, and select **Connect** - and the issue is gone. I have no idea why this works, but maybe you can use this approach in your solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute the code above within a `Task` (i.e. a separate thread) it just works. If the credentials are not present or stale at the location in the registry (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47649081/4090370)) a window opens and you can authenticate yourself.

Can anyone explain why this works?

Comment: After wasting 7 days, this thread has been a savior. Using Task fixes the problem.

Comment: @thepace Me too :-)

Comment: I've tried looking into this problem every several months or so and this is the only time it's worked for me. Thanks @participant. It's so difficult to find this question/answer too since it's got so little up votes. My guess for why it works is something to do with the UI thread not working with the Prompt. I don't know why Microsoft wouldn't have that documented though.

Answer (score 2):

VS has added a registry entry to store the credential, try to delete the entry in the following path:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp

**Update:**

Also, try the code below to see whether it works:

```
 var credentials = new VssClientCredentials();
 credentials.PromptType = CredentialPromptType.PromptIfNeeded;
 credentials.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(storageKind: "VssApp2", storageNamespace: "VisualStudio");
 var aTeamProjects = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/"), credentials);
 aTeamProjects.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

Comment: Found the key and deleted it. Sorry, the exception is still thrown.

Comment: Have you relaunched VS? Please also try to close all Visual Studio instances and delete %LOCALAPPDATA%\.IdentityService.

Comment: It's still throwing :(

Comment: Doesn't help :(

Comment: Are you able to login VSTS from browser on this machine? Do you have other client machine to test this api?

Comment: Browser sign-on is working perfectly but running the app even on different machines fails.

Comment: Could you share your entire code? Have you specify the correct Uri?

Comment: I shared the complete code. The URI is `https://<xxx>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`. I intentively tried a wrong URI and the exception thrown changed to host not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160693/discussion-between-participant-and-cece-dong-msft).

Comment: Are you able to get credential window prompted?

Comment: No, there is no prompt, only the exception.

Comment: Once you delete registry entry of VS, you should get prompt. Do you delete the correct registry entry? Which version of VS are you using?